# Defining fields in concurrent environment

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have two methods in my class, which will be executed within concurrent environment:

```
class Clazz {

  private int counter = 0;
  private volatile Map<..> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  private int[] array;

  public void concurrentMethod() {
    ...perform some actions with map...
  }

  public int nonConcurrentMethod() {
    ...reinitialize the map...change references...
    counter++;
    return array[counter];
  }

}
```

The question is following: assuming that `nonConcurrentMethod` is to be called by only one thread at a time, should I explicitly specify `counter` and `array` as a `volatile` fields? Make counter `atomic`?

My thoughts are it'd be better to insure that everything should work without glitches on a real production.

Comment: I think there is no need to make your map as volatile. ConcurrentHashMap by itself is thread safe, better make it final.

Comment: @MukeshVerma what if I change the reference and reinitialize this map in `nonConcurrentMethod`? All other threads actively using `concurrentMethod` should see the updated field

Comment: since you have marked it as final you can't really reassign the reference.

Comment: @MukeshVerma my bad, description is fixed

Comment: If you are so sure that your nonConcurrent function will not be called by more than one thread at a time, I think you don't need to do anything else .Making things as atomic , volatile or marking your function as synchronised will have an additional overhead , avoid if you don't need them.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether `nonConcurrentMethod()` is “called by only one thread at a time”, it requires thread safe constructs to ensure visibility of the changes made in one invocation to the next invocation by a different thread. But what’s the problem with making the method `synchronized` when it is supposed to be “called by only one thread at a time” anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's the entire class which has specific thread-safe semantics e.g. `HashMap` is not thread-safe while `ConcurrentHashMap` is. This is especially important if you are building a library, people might go around your design by calling `nonConcurrentMethod()` from multiple threads.

IMO if you can't split `Clazz` into two separate classes with different thread-safe semantics it would be prudent to make `nonConcurrentMethod()` thread-safe. In case `nonConcurrentMetho()` is called from multiple threads  the performance will degrade but the correctness will be retained, hopefully avoiding hard to find bugs.

You can try an internal lock, which hopefully will not be too costly due to biased locking optimizing it when the lock is acquired from a single thread:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

public int nonConcurrentMethod() {
  synchronized(lock) {
    ...reinitialize the map...change references...
    counter++;
    return array[counter];
  }
}
```

Make sure that at least one of the `Clazz` fields is `final` to ensure [safe publication](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_publication).

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have given indvidual modifications from to the `map` will be seen by users of `concurrentMethod`, but the modifications made inside a method call are not isolated from another method call of any other method. Therefore, if `nonConcurrentMethod` at some point `clear()`s the map, `concurrentMethod` might see entries disappear from the `map` between invocations of methods on the map.

For example:

```
concurrentMethod() {
    System.out.println(map.size());
    System.out.println(map.size());
}
```

Could output:

```
10
0
```

If `nonConcurrentMethod` clears the map and is called while `concurrentMethod` is running.

If you want to ensure atomic access, then rather than using `ConcurrentHashMap`, try using a normal `HashMap` and protecting it by protecting the methods with the `synchronized` keyword or by using more granular locking, either through `synchronized(lock) { }` or by using some of the locking tools provided in the Java concurrency package, such as the `ReadWriteLock` interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to move shared objects in a different class that are accessible by multiple threads.

It can create serious problem in longer run due to such a mess and will be difficult to find the root cause for developer who never worked on this module.

Try to make to code clean in such a way that there is no possibility of any hidden bug or assumption in the code implementation.

---

Even all the methods in `ConcurrentHashMap` are thread safe still we have to take care to ensure the thread safety when different thread safe methods called by multiple threads.

For example:

```
Map map = new ConcurrentHashMap();

Thread t1 = new Thread();
Thread t2 = new Thread();

public void putIfAbsent(String key, String value) {
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

In above sample example we have shared resource `map` and two threads are putting some values if absent.

To avoid such situation we can use two technique as mentioned below;

- Either each caller will make sure to make it thread safe (client-side)
- Or define new method at one place to ensure thread safety (server-side **Preferable**)